# a contest web site and it's data base

Tags: database, django, database-design, web

I'm designing a contest web site with django. each time many teams can participate in the contest and each team can have maximum 3 members. I want to know what's the best way to do it. (the information and history about contests must be available). i have 2 choices:

1. i can save all data about previous contest and it's information(teams, users, challenges and ...) and create new contest in previous db.
2. i can backup previous data base and clear it after each contest finished.

I want to know which of the above are better and what is normal way?

thanks a lot.

Comment: If it's not in the database any more, you can't query it - so you can't get old results. Seems like a bit of a non-question? Perhaps you're missing the concept of storing a `CompetitionId` and associating all records with it? Databases are designed to hold many many pieces of information - take advantage of that

Answer (score 0):

Choose solution 1 if you want to access the old data later. Solution 2 is better only if you can ommit the backup.